# angularjs - ng-dirty class on input type number / $valid is true when entering text

Tags: javascript, validation, angularjs

What I want is an input, number only, which have a red border when you type anything but a number to it.

What I did is

```
<input ng-model="number" name="number" type="number" step="any" />
```

and this

```
.ng-dirty.ng-invalid {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

now if you type in "blah blah", it's gonna be `$valid == false` BUT it's not gonna have a red border, because typing in "blah blah" won't update the model thus won't put ng-dirty class to the input. I obviously don't want the input to be red bordered right away, how do I deal with this?

You can test it here http://plnkr.co/edit/HWGKkzmxVx0GYIiRGyqX?p=preview

Thanks.

PS: I'm on chrome, using 1.1.5

// edit

when I remove the `required` it's even gonna be valid http://plnkr.co/edit/E763TRUnYr47xwGqJOkG?p=preview apparently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's browser "bug"(it's actually expected behaviour) see https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2144 there are some workarounds, such as this https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/pRc5pu3bWQ0/discussion

or you could write your own input directive using the same principles

```
app.directive('input', [function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function(scope, el, attrs, ctrl) {
            if (attrs.type == 'number' && typeof el.prop('validity') !== 'undefined') {
                el.on('keyup change', function() {
                    var validity = el.prop('validity');
                    ctrl.$setValidity('badInput', !validity.badInput);                      
                });
            }
        }
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you probably mean something like that, which would works perfectly:

```
.ng-dirty.ng-invalid {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

As shown by the [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3aform.FormController), the `dirty` state isn't set when the model changes, but whenever the user interacts with the form, so probably rather when the view changes.

**EDIT:**

According to your plunker, your error is to put the `no-validate` attribute on the `<input>` tag, rather than on the `<form>` tag. See [the corrected plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/HWGKkzmxVx0GYIiRGyqX?p=preview).

Comment: Well, on Firefox, there is no border at the beginning, and it appears when one types a non-number. Is that what you want ? Which browser are you using ?

Comment: There is a bug with number validation. I've posted it on google group page but got no reply. if You enter alphabets in number field it validates the field to true.

Comment: Remove the required tag and everything is valid inside the input type number. Tested with both IE and Chrome so let's hope for an update from angular-team

Answer (score 0):

you have a typo:

```
.ng-dirty.ng-invalid {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: yeah thanks, but that's not the problem, only made that typo when I was creating the post, it's .ng-dirty.ng-invalid in my actual code..

Comment: so you want it to only show the border if the value is not empty, is invalid and is dirty?

Comment: exactly, but .ng-dirty is not added unless you put a number inside, so typing in "shizzle" won't make the border red, if I used .ng-invalid only, it would work, but input would be red bordered right away, which is something I do not want